# How to Push a Secondarily Defined Lettrine Out of the Margin of the Page

Tags: macros, margins, paragraphs, lettrine, leftmargin

I am working on a document in which I would like to incorporate a secondary lettrine outside of the one which is mainly used.

Consider the code

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor} % für farbigen Text
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\newcommand{\SecondaryLettrine}[5][]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\normalfont#2}%
  \lettrine[#1]{#4}{\normalfont#3#5}%
  \endgroup
}

\newcommand{\LettrineA}[2]{%
  \SecondaryLettrine[lines=3,lhang=0,findent=.15em]
    {\normalfont}
    {\scshape}
    {\color{black}#1}
    {#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setmainfont{cabin} 

\noindent This is a non-indented leadoff sentence.
\vskip 10pt
\LettrineA{H}{ow} may I put the drop cap entirely to the right of the left-hand margin of the page?---lhang=0 in the preamble seems to have no effect. \lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

which produces

[image]

I don't know why the newly defined lettrine is not starting where a non-indented paragraph would start. Alos, `lhang=0` in the preamble seems to have no effect.

QUESTION: How may I correct this so that the defined lettrine starts where a non-indented paragraph would start? I compile the code with `lualatex`.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\lettrine` needs to be used just before the start of the paragraph, and its settings need to be in scope for the whole paragrah, so the paragraph shape is in force at the end.  Your example had `\lettrine` after the first line and in a group that ended before letterine was used at all. Safest would be to remove the grouping but I left it in but delayed the end of group here as I didn't know the intention of the group.

[image]

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{xcolor} % für farbigen Text
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[sfdefault]{cabin}

\newcommand{\SecondaryLettrine}[5][]{%
  \begingroup
  \renewcommand{\LettrineFontHook}{\normalfont#2}%
  \lettrine[#1]{#4}{\normalfont#3#5}%
  \def\par{\endgraf\endgroup}%
}

\newcommand{\LettrineA}[2]{%
  \SecondaryLettrine[lines=3,lhang=0,findent=.15em]
    {\normalfont}
    {\scshape}
    {\color{black}#1}
    {#2}%
}

\begin{document}
\Large
\thispagestyle{empty}
\setmainfont{cabin} 

\noindent This is a non-indented leadoff sentence.

\vskip 10pt
\LettrineA{H}{ow} may I put the drop cap entirely to the right of the left-hand margin of the page?---lhang=0 in the preamble seems to have no effect. \lipsum[12]
\end{document}
```

Comment: actually it was a the start of the paragraph implicitly as you used the primitive `\vskip` rather than the latex command `\vspace`  but having an explicit paragraph break before the lettrine is a lot clearer.